# what is the best strategy for a log analyze applications

Tags: java, ajax, rest, jsf

i will develop a web application to view and analyze log files from both remote machines and locally and planning to use java. At first glance it seems like application must work with big data sets effectively. For example to list a log file on browser i should implement a paginated list working with ajax (server will give data accordingly with current page number). Also i like to use AJAX.

My question is how should i design an application like this. i have three possibilities:

- AJAX with RESTful service.
- JSP and servlet
- JSF with AJAX

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you have a look at Chainsaw - http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html - and Lilith - http://lilith.huxhorn.de/ - to see how others have approached this.

Comment: Indeed, see if you can use either of these as-is, and save yourself a pile of effort.

Answer (score 0):

The released version of Chainsaw is pretty old - a MAJOR update will be released shortly.  If you want to try out a pre-release version, you can see a screenshot and get the tarball or Mac DMG here:

http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy/